# How to use cocos2d's collision_model

Tags: python, cocos2d-python

Recently, I used `cocos2d` with `Python` to make a game. But I had trouble with the `collision_model`. I read the [documentation](http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/api/cocos.collision_model.html) but I still can't use the `CollisionManager` to add the `CollidableSprite` as in the [example](http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/collision.html#what-an-object-must-comply-to-be-collidable).

In fact, I had to change the `ActorSprite` to `CollidableSprite` to avoid an Error. What could the problem be?

```
import cocos.euclid as eu
import cocos.collision_model as cm

class CollidableSprite(cocos.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, center_x, center_y, radius):
        super(ActorSprite, self).__init__(image)
        self.position = (center_x, center_y)
        self.cshape = cm.CircleShape(eu.Vector2(center_x, center_y), radius)

class ActorModel(object):
    def __init__(self, cx, cy, radius):
        self.cshape = cm.CircleShape(eu.Vector2(center_x, center_y), radius)
```

The documentation showed this example initialising the collidable sprite. But where does the `ActorSprite` come from? I have to change it to `CollidableSprite` to make the class work. And I state a collision manager to add the sprites. But it returns `None` when I call the function `CollisionManeger.known_objs()`.

```
 def __init__(self):
    super(page,self).__init__()
    self.collision_manager = CollisionManager()
    self.collision_manager.add(self.sprite1)
    self.collision_manager.add(self.sprite2)
    print self.collision_manager.known_objs()
```

So, is there something wrong with the documentation? Or have I misunderstood it somehow?

Comment: Forgive my poor English

Comment: Can you explain with more detail what trouble you're having? Also please edit in your code. With code and more info someone can edit your question to make it easier to follow (if it's unclear because of your english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the example should indeed initialize a `CollidableSprite` instead of an `ActorSprite`.

`CollisionManager` class is just an interface. It doesn't do anything. There are two implementations in [collision_model](http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/api/cocos.collision_model.html): `CollisionManagerBruteForce` and `CollisionManagerGrid`. So you can use for example:

```
self.collision_manager = CollisionManagerBruteForce()
```

but note that `CollisionManagerGrid` [is more efficient](http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/collision.html#comparing-with-brute-force).

Comment: I add the sprite successfully by using the **CollisionManagerBruteForce()**.Thanks, tython!